# How do I add up all the numbers in the list box?

Tags: c#, if-statement, while-loop, listbox

I want to add up all the numbers in the list box(while still keeping the numbers in it) after the while loop is completed.

```
    void Task3()
    {
        limit = Convert.ToInt32(tBNumber.Text);
        int finalN = limit + 100;
        int n = limit;
        int sum = 0;
        while (n < finalN )
        {
            if (n % 9 == 0)
            {
                lbAnswer.Items.Add(n);
                n++;
            }
            else
            {
                n++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increment `sum` by `n` just after you add it to the listbox.

```
if (n % 9 == 0)
{
    lbAnswer.Items.Add(n);
    sum += n;
    n++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid some iterations.

```
void Task3()
    {
        int n, limit;
        n, limit = Convert.ToInt32(tBNumber.Text.Trim());
        int sum = 0;
        while (n < limit + 100)
        {
            if (n % 9 == 0)
            {
                lbAnswer.Items.Add(n);
                sum += n;
                n += 9;
            }
            else
                n++;
        }
    }
```